# How to remove an element of a sequence A from List[A] that is a value of a map(B->List[A])

Tags: scala

#### I have this data:

```scala
//H1 = house name
//H2 = price
//H3 = size
//H4 = location

//List(H1, H2, H3, H4)

val houses = List(
  ("House_A", 250, 120, "NYC"),
  ("House_B", 90, 100, "BR"),
  ("House_C", 300, 500, "BR"),
  ("House_D", 120, 90, "NYC"),
  ("House_E", 320, 250, "BR"),
  ("House_F", 290, 450, "SA"),
  ("House_G", 290, 450, "NYC"),
  ("House_F", 450, 100, "FR"),
  ("House_H", 210, 92, "SA"),
  ("House_I", 240, 100, "FR"),
  ("House_J", 395, 80, "FR"),
  ("House_K", 140, 125, "NYC"),
  ("House_L", 900, 250, "BR"),
  ("House_M", 300, 110, "FR")
)
```

and want to get to **"List places with Houses with price(H1) > 100 and more than 1 house"** in this format:

`List((H4, List(H1,H2,H3)))`

#### The Problem

My problem is that I can't figure out how to remove H4(place) from the list that is supposed to be List(H1,H2,H3).

#### What I tried

This is as good as I got it

```scala
houses
  .filter(_._2 > 100)
  .groupBy(_._4)
  .filter(a => a._2.length > 1) // this is the map I talk about in the title: Map(H4 -> List(H1, H2, H3, H4))
  .toList
```

```scala
List(
  (BR,List((House_C,300,500,BR), (House_E,320,250,BR), (House_L,900,250,BR))),
  (NYC,List((House_A,250,120,NYC), (House_D,120,90,NYC), (House_G,290,450,NYC), (House_K,140,125,NYC))),
  (FR,List((House_F,450,100,FR), (House_I,240,100,FR), (House_J,395,80,FR), (House_M,300,110,FR))),
  (SA,List((House_F,290,450,SA), (House_H,210,92,SA))))
```

Comment: Just add `.view.mapValues(_.map(y => (y._1, y._2, y._3)))` after the filter (scala 2.13) or just `.mapValues(_.map(y => (y._1, y._2, y._3)))` for earlier versions of Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were too close!
You only need to `map` the inner group so you can remove the unwanted *column*. And, sicne you need to do that for each inner group, you want to `map` all the **Map**.

```
houses
  .filter(_._2 > 100)
  .groupBy(_._4)
  .filter(a => a._2.length > 1)
  .map {
    case (location, group) =>
      location -> group.map {
        case (house, price, size, _) =>
          (house, price, size)
      }
  }.toList
```

---

**Bonus:** To make the code more efficient you can.

- Combine `filter` & `map` into `collect`.
- You do not need all the size of the list, just check if it is greater than 1.
  *(this one only applies for Scala `2.13 +`)*

-

```
houses
  .filter(_._2 > 100)
  .groupBy(_._4)
  .collect {
    case (location, group) if (group.sizeIs > 1) =>
      location -> group.map {
        case (house, price, size, _) =>
          (house, price, size)
      }
  }.toList
```

Comment: 0. Thanks a ton, I'd not have cracked that one.
1. Can we only use case(A,B) when we use a Map because key, value? 
2. Instead of the wildcard in the second case statement, could we have called it "location" and just not used it?

Comment: @TobiasKolb 0. You are welcome. 1. The base pattern has to be `(K, V)` because that is what each element of a **Map** is, however you can keep matching the nested values, for example, if the key is another tuple and the value is a case class you can `case ((k1, k2), CaseClass(a, b, c)) =>`. 2. Yes, however many people _(including me)_ like to have all warnings on and turn them into errors, unused values are one of such warnings; I prefer to just put the `_` but I believe you can do something like `location @ _` to name it and still do not get a warning.